# Texture stretches and grows instead of repeating in Blender 2.8

Tags: modeling, rendering, mesh, texturing, uv

I created a plane with a ground texture that has a displacement map to simulate the depth for the rocks and I made it slightly uneven with a cloud displacement modifier.

Now, I want to make this repeat and be larger but if I try to scale it up, everything increases in size when I want it to repeat.  I tried copying and pasting the plane and putting them next to each other but this is sloppy and I feel like it takes up too much resources.

Anyone have any insight on how to achieve what I'm going for? I appreciate it, thanks.

*Shading Nodes*
[image]

*How my scene Looks*
[image]

*What I mean by stretching and growing*
[image]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)