# Tiling a texture with displacement map

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, displacement, scale

so I recently asked a question about tiling a texture so it won't stretch and grow but just repeat.  I got an answer which worked, however it did not take in account the displacement, so while the texture image tiles correctly, the displacement looks all wonky.  If anyone knows the setting to fix this, I'd be very appreciative. Thanks.

[Here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163182/texture-stretches-and-grows-instead-of-repeating-in-blender-2-8?noredirect=1#comment275895_163182)
 is the link to my original question with some pics.

Comment: Looking at your image from the question you linked, it seems you haven't put the the vector output of the 'Mapping' node; you can plug that into more than one image texture. That should fix the problem.

Comment: @ParallelMayhem Okay, so right now I have a displacement modifier that is attached to the displacement texture picture.  So what you're saying is to leave that the way it is, and also put the image onto the node panel and connect the Mapping node to that picture as well as the base image texture and then connect the displacement picture node to what?

Comment: On the displacement modifier settings, you can try changing the texture coordinates to "global" instead of "local". Personally I would do the displacement in the shader and not via a modifier. Check out this video that talks about microdisplacement. 
https://www.blendernation.com/2019/01/23/daily-blender-tip-146-quickly-set-up-microdisplacements/

Comment: @crazycourier Thank you!! I appreciate it